Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.3.2'] was not found in any of the following sources:
I encountered this error while deploying the code on Jenkins but in my local its working.
* Where:
Build file '/opt/apps/reelservicesjenkins/jobs/Pipeline/tgservice_devops_pipeline_uat/master/779/devcode/tg-api/build.gradle' line: 10

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '3.3.2'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (No included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.3.2')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    maven(http://com.central-repo.reel.com:8081/repository/maven-proxy-group/)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Current versions in my system as well jenkins server
JAVA: 21
gradle : 8.10
springboot : 3.3.2

Here is the dir structure and build.gradle files
tg-service
---tg-api
  ---build.gradle
---tg-common
  ---build.gradle
---tg-data-access
  ---build.gradle
---build.gradle
---wrapper
----gradle-wrapper.property

here is dependancies
1.build.gradle(tg-api)
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "10.17.3"
 id 'java'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
        url = "$repositoryUrl"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }

}
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'com.map.tg.api'
description = "map tg"
bootJar {
enabled = true
}
dependencies {
implementation project(":tg-common")
implementation project(":tg-data-access")
}

2.build.gradle(tg-common)
`
`plugins {     
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'     
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4' 
 id 'java'
  } 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
        url = "$repositoryUrl"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }

}
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' 
group = 'com.map.tg.common' 
description = "map tg"``


build.gradle(tg-data-access)

plugins {     
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.3.2'     
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4' 
 id 'java'
} 
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
    maven {
        url = "$repositoryUrl"
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
    }

}
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' 
group = 'com.map.tg.data-access' 
description = "map tg"

subprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url = "$repositoryUrl"
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }

    }
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "jacoco"

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = '21'
    }
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
        finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
    }
    jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test
        reports {
            xml.required = true
        }
    }
    build.dependsOn jacocoTestReport
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }
    dependencies {
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.3.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.3.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:3.3.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.3.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:3.3.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:3.3.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign:4.1.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.1.1"
        implementation "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config:4.1.1"
        implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:3.2.2"
        implementation "org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:3.2.2"
        implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0"
        implementation "io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-annotations:2.2.15"
        implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:6.3.3"
        implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.3.2.Final"
        implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:8.0.1.Final"
        implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.16.1"
        implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.16.1"
        implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus:1.13.0"
        implementation "io.micrometer:micrometer-core:1.13.0"
        implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30"
        implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.12.3"
        implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.12.3"
        implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-impl:0.12.3"
        implementation "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-jackson:0.12.3"
        implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1"
        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.13.0"
        implementation "commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4"
        implementation "org.json:json:20231013"
        implementation "com.zaxxer:HikariCP:5.1.0"
        implementation "io.lettuce:lettuce-core:6.3.2.RELEASE"
        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.12.0"
        implementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.15"
        implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.22.1"
        implementation "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.22.1"
        implementation "com.hazelcast:hazelcast-all:4.2.8"
        implementation "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.21"
        implementation "com.github.ulisesbocchio:jasypt-spring-boot:3.0.5"
        implementation "org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.3"
        implementation "org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.1.10"
        implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.25.0"
        implementation "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.17.0"
        runtimeOnly "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0"
        testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test"
        testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.25.1"
        testImplementation "com.h2database:h2:2.2.224"
        testImplementation "org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter:1.19.0"
        implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2"
        implementation "io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2"
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.2.0"
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2"
        testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2"
        testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:4.0.0"
        testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2"
        implementation "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.3"
        implementation "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.1"
    }
}

info.yml
``service_name: 'tgservice'
microservice_name: 'api'
build_type: '/opt/apps/compiler_softwares/gradle-8.10/bin/gradle'
build_path: 'tg-api/build/libs'
build_command: '/opt/apps/compiler_softwares/gradle-8.10/bin/gradle :tg-api:clean :tg-api:build --refresh-dependencies'
testcase_repo: 'http://git.com.reel.com/FnLQA/TgService_APIAutomation.git'
code_coverage: '0.0'
vertical: 'reel'
java_version: 'jdk21'`

please help me understand what I might be doing wrong
